# Ubuntu 18.04 login screen loop

Tags: login

When I tried to turn off Ubuntu I noticed a message about some updates. I checked the box and after some time the PC turned off.
When I tried to turn it on, I am at a login screen and is a loop. No matter how many times I enter my password, I am stuck to that.

I have read on Internet about this loop but:
- some of the solutions imply to acces Ctrl + alt + F1/F2/F3 but nothing happend.
- some imply to copy some bash file under Terminal which I do not how to do it.

I tried to use TimeShift via Live CD and I restored to a much earlier time but the login screen loop stills persists.

What in the world should I do?

Comment: You could try to boot Ubuntu into text mode. Then from there you can fix the graphical login problem.